# Excel - How to prompt for user input in a cell, after entering a value in a different cell, without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am updating a spreadsheet designed to capture survey information from users in the field. For this reason I cannot use VBA as the spreadsheet will be completed using a mobile device.

When the user enters a value in one cell (Free text entry for an item name), is there way to prompt the user to enter a value in another cell (Numerical quantity of that item) without using VBA? I have experimented with formulas in Data Validation but have so far had no luck. The closest I can get is the input message of Data Validation reminding the user to enter a quantity, however this will likely be ignored by some users and result in survey forms being returned without quantities if there is no way to force the user to enter a quantity value.

Comment: By "mobile device", do you mean a web-hosted interface to worksheet on a server??

Comment: No, usually a smartphone or a tablet running the mobile version of Excel. The completed workbook is emailed back to the office. Your interpretation sounds like it could solve my problem but is way above my capability.

Comment: What do you mean, when you say "Prompt"? A message in a cell in Excel or a MsgBox?

Comment: A message box, or an error message preventing further activity until the required value has been entered.

Comment: I have never seen a workbook that would create an error message w/o using VBA.

Comment: Data Validation can create Stop, Warning or Information error messages. That's what I had in mind, or at least something similar.

Answer (score 0):

See if this answers your question:
Suppose you have a prompt in Cell A1 ("Enter a number in Cell A2")
You enter a number in A2, and you have another prompt in Cell D2 ("Enter another number in Cell D2"). Enter the following line in Cell D1:

```
=IF(A2<>"","Enter another number in Cell D2","")
```

Comment: I have a Data Validation Input Message reminding the user to enter a value into the necessary cell. The problem is that the users have a tendency to ignore any messages that don't prevent them from taking further action. If the Data Validation were set to only accept a number between 1 - 30 and the user entered 31, they would not be allowed to continue without editing or deleting that number. I'd like something similar, but with the focus on another cell.